# Why is Stack Overflow saying it can't post my question because it contains an image when, in fact, there is no image in the posting?

Tags: support, asking-questions, images

I’m trying to post a question on this web site but every time I try to post the text containing the question I get the following error message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>   we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

What I don’t understand is that there aren’t any images in my text.

It’s just text!

I know it’s just text because I wrote the entire thing up in Microsoft Word before I pasted it into Stack Overflow.

What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 15):

Microsoft Word might be introducing some artifacts in the copy process. I would try copying it to something like [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) first, and then re-copy/paste into the interface to see if it lets you post the (now definitely) plain text.

Answer (score 4):

If your post contains something that looks like `![text][1]` or `![text](text)` or some slight variations of those, then it will be interpreted as an image. Try selecting your source code and clicking the button with two curly brackets when you compose your post and it'll convert that into a code block, which will ignore those image markups.

Comment: If that's not it, and Zypher's suggestion doesn't work, try posting larger and larger portions of your post, and find when the error occurs.  Try it out as an answer here first so you don't submit malformed questions to stack overflow.